# Como lo resuelvo?

Tags: java

a)      En la clase jugador crear un método imprimir() donde se debe mostrar en consola  todos los datos del jugador.

b)     Crear la clase Portero, que hereda de Jugador y que tiene los siguientes atributos privados: más sus getters y setters

- ```
     golesRecibidos de tipo int para indicar el número de goles encajados.
  ```
- ```
     penaltisParados de tipo int para indicar el número de penaltis parados.
  ```

c)      Crear un constructor para dar valor a todos los atributos de la clase Portero, incluidos los heredados. Deberá usar el constructor de la clase Jugador.

d)     Crear un constructor vacío donde no a recibido ningún gol y no a tapado ningún penalti con el resto de datos en cero similar al de la clase Jugador.

e)      En la clase portero Sobrescribir el método imprimir más los propios de la clase .

f)      Crear una clase main, donde se registaran al menos 5 objetos  de jugadores y 5 objetos de porteros.

g)      Crear una colección donde pueda almacenar los 10 objetos en la misma colección

h)     Crear un método en la clase main que sirva para recorrer e imprimir  la colección usada para almacenar los 10 objetos

Solo tengo este código:

public class Jugador {

```
  private String nombre;
  private String posición;
  private int partidosJugados;
  private int golesMarcados;
  private int tarjetasAmarillas;
  private int tarjetasRojas;
  protected static int identificador;
  public Jugador (String n, String d, int p, int g, int a, int r){
        nombre = n;
        posición = d;
        partidosJugados = p;
        golesMarcados = g;
        tarjetasAmarillas = a;
        tarjetasRojas = r;
        identificador ++;
```

}

```
  public Jugador (){
        this("sin nombre", "sin demarcacion", 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

}

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluye que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema.

Comment: Se debe incluir que se ha intentado normalmente este tipo de preguntas no son bien recibidas